# Make an Accordion option expanded

Tags: jquery, accordion

I'm using the code below to have a multi level menu. The only dark point is that I don't know how to make an option active. I mean the accordion to be expanded in a specific option.

```
<div class="accordion">
<h1><a href="">No Sub 1<span class="label label-info" style="float:right;">17</span></a></h1>
<h1>With Sub<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left:8px;"></i><span class="label label-info" style="float:right;">17</span></h1>
<div>
    <h2>With Sub-Sub<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left:8px;"></i><span class="label label-info" style="float:right;">17</span></h2>
    <div>
        <h3>With Sub-Sub-Sub<i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left:8px;"></i><span class="label label-info" style="float:right;">17</span></h3>
        <div>
            <h4><a href="">Final level 1<span class="label label-info" style="float:right;">17</span></a></h4>
            <h4><a href="">Final level 2<span class="label label-info" style="float:right;">17</span></a></h4>
            <h4><a href="">Final level 3<span class="label label-info" style="float:right;">17</span></a></h4>
        </div>
        <h3><a href="">Without Sub-Sub-Sub<span class="label label-info" style="float:right;">17</span></a></h3>
    </div>
    <h2><a href="">No Sub-Sub<span class="label label-info" style="float:right;">17</span></a></h2>
</div>
<h1><a href="">Without Sub 2<span class="label label-info" style="float:right;">17</span></a></h1>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var headers = ["H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6"];
    $(".accordion").click(function(e) {
        var target = e.target,
        name = target.nodeName.toUpperCase();

        if($.inArray(name,headers) > -1) {
            var subItem = $(target).next();

            //slideUp all elements (except target) at current depth or greater
            var depth = $(subItem).parents().length;
            var allAtDepth = $(".accordion p, .accordion div").filter(function() {
                if($(this).parents().length >= depth && this !== subItem.get(0)) {
                    return true; 
                }
            });
            $(allAtDepth).slideUp("fast");

            //slideToggle target content and adjust bottom border if necessary
            subItem.slideToggle("fast",function() {
                $(".accordion :visible:last").css("border-radius","0 0 0px 0px");
            });
            $(target).css({"border-bottom-right-radius":"0", "border-bottom-left-radius":"0"});
        }
    })
});
```

Does anyone knows a way to make one of href active in the meaning that the parent div will be expanded?

Thank you